# Partial sum formula for $\sum_{n=0}^{x} {\tan(x)}$ from $(0,\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I know there is no elementary way of expressing the partial sums of $\tan(x)$. I know; however, I can get an approximation of partial sums using a series, such as the MacLaurin series. If a series can have partial sum formulas by taking non-elementary summations in terms of polynomials I could get a rough approximation. The only problems is that most of time the series do not have absolute convergence nor are they accurate enough.

First I could take the Maclaurin series of $\tan(x)$, but the series converges from $1<x<1$.

Then I could $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$

So I could take..
$$\sin(x)\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right)$$
$$\sin(x)\sec(x)$$

If I take the MacLaurin series of $\sin(x)$. 
$$(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...)(\sec(x))$$

I can take the partial sum of the polynomials, but when the polynomials are multiplied  to $\sec(x)$ there are no elementary partial sum formulas that can describe them. If I did the opposite by instead taking the MacLaurin series of $\sec(x)$, and multiplying it by $\sin(x)$ the series would converge only from $-1<x<1$.

I have one more idea, but that would require a series for $\frac{1}{x}$ **that would need to converge from** $(1,\infty)$ **in terms of polynomials or sine and cosine**.

Let's say this series of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B(x)$.

We can take the following...

$$\sin(x)*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B(\cos(x))$$

Since there are partial sums for sines and cosines I could find an approximate partial sum for $\tan(x)$.

Could you improve on what I put down? Is there other simpler techniques that could be used to approximate the partial sum formula for $\tan(x)$?

Comment: Since $\tan x$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}^+$, you will never have a uniform approximation. The magnitude of $\tan x$ depends on how close $x\pmod{\pi}$ is to $\pi/2$, hence the most effective way to approximate such partial sums (for which purpose, by the way?) is to make a clever use of equidistribution theorems.

Comment: And, by the way, the sums $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\tan n$ *cannot* be bounded like for the sine or cosine function. The reason is that $\pi$ has an infinite number of convergents with an even numerator, hence for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\tan n|\geq (1-\varepsilon) n$. Consider, for instance, $n=11$ (corresponding to $\pi\approx 22/7$) or $n=52174$ (corresponding to $\pi\approx 104348/33215$).

Comment: Is there any other possible series I could use for tan(x), and if not that any techniques outside using a series.

Comment: I tried using MacLaurin series to converge to a partial sum. This partial sum could be used for fractional values of a partial sum. Perhaps it could be used in statistics.

Comment: Arbuja, use $\tan x = \tan(x\pmod{\pi})$ and the fact that the sequence $\{n\pmod{\pi}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is equidistributed. I already said, no Taylor series can approximate an unbounded function. Again, for what purpose do you need to approximate such sums?

Comment: To find some technique used for computing partial sums for fractional arguments. You have probably heard of asymptotic series, laurent series, etc. Is integration techniques possible.

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that $\tan x$ is not an analytic function over the whole $\mathbb{R}$, and you want to approximate $\tan n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so you are looking for the holy grail.

Comment: Ok you're probably correct, but I heard of a series. It needs a DiGamma Function, so it is not an elementary approximation. It has absolute convergence on $\tan(x)$. I'll show it as quickly as I can.

Comment: Ok, in such sense you can exploit the fact that $$\tan x=\frac{d}{dx}\log\cos x$$ and $\cos x$ has a nice Weierstrass product.

Comment: So $$\tan x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8x}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2-4x^2}.$$

Comment: My desmos calculator can only graph trig, exponential, polynomials, and combinations. Perhaps you could show me using an advanced calculator like python, or SciLab